# Populating Data in TableView by scrolling

Tags: scroll, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to familiarise myself with Java-FX.
I have an ObservableArrayList with approx. 100000 values and I want to populate them in a TableView.
I noticed that populating all data in a TableView performs very slow. Therefore, I decided to improve the performance by
deviding the data set into 10 blocks with 10000 values. Each block should be populated when the scrollBar of the table
reaches its end position. I want to realize it a listiner similar to swing.
Is there an out-of-the-box functionality in Java8 for my problem or any ideas of how to do it?

Here is a code snippet of how I load the file and put the data in the TableView

```
@FXML private void loadFile() { 
    IOFileOperations io = new IOFileOperations();
        data = io.getData();
        if (data==null) {
            table.setItems(null);                
        }
        else {
            int dataSizeRow=data.size();
            int colNumSize = io.getNumberOfColumns();
            DataManager.setColNums(colNumSize);
            DataManager.setDatas(data);                
            for(int i=0;i<colNumSize;i++) {
                final int x=i; 
                String tmp="["+Integer.toString(i+1)+"]";
                column = new TableColumn<>(tmp);
                column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dataProperty(x));                    
                table.getColumns().add(column);
            }
            table.setItems(data);                
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you populating the tableview?  I have loaded tableviews with tens of thousands of rows with no noticeable performance hit.

Comment: @purring pigeon I populated the data similar to this link [link](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/). My CPU needs ~8seconds to show 100000 data values

Comment: "8 seconds to show 100000 data values" doesn't make sense. You can't "show 100000 data values" (unless you have a spectacularly large video screen). Do you mean it takes that long to load them (from where?) and put them in the table's items list? Can you post some code that shows what you're doing?

Comment: @James_D I've added a code snippet.

Comment: So what actually takes the time? It looks like you are loading these from I/O: I would assume that is the time-consuming part, not creating the columns and setting the data. Why not just do that part in a background thread?

Comment: @James_D background thread? yes that could be an option for me, thanks.